# Regexp PHP, extract id and replace

Tags: php, regex

I have a php `$variable` with a string :

```
 '<iframe width=\"660\" height=\"370\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" src=\"http:\/\/api.dmcloud.net\/embed\/53b5149794739966184c1a71\/548f065806361d7e915cc89e?preset=543e41ca06361d414ze777c8\"><\/iframe>'
```

I need do to some treatments in the tag src in this variable. I have to use regexp, str_replace etc...

First I need to extract the second ID in src, in my example it's `548f065806361d7e915cc89e` and after that, replace all the src tag with an other string like src=\"My_New_String/ID_Extracted\"

How can i do that with regexp ? Or other ?

Thanks !

EDIT : I forgot to specify, i have more strings before and after my `<iframe>`, like :

```
 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX<iframe width=\"660\" height=\"370\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" src=\"http:\/\/api.dmcloud.net\/embed\/53b5149794739966184c1a71\/548f065806361d7e915cc89e?preset=543e41ca06361d414ze777c8\"><\/iframe>XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

Comment: And what you have tried so far

Comment: Take a look here http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: I'm first trying to extract src tag.. ^src=\"(.)\"$, but regexp is not really my speciality

Comment: Are you trying to extract or replace ?

Comment: Both ;) Check my edit

Comment: See my answer it is irrelevant of what is around the iframe or how many iframes there are.

Comment: Yeah, but i think the @PedroLobito solution is better and easier. I have only one iframe. Edit : or not, i like your solution chris85

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$iframe = '<iframe width=\"660\" height=\"370\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" src=\"http:\/\/api.dmcloud.net\/embed\/53b5149794739966184c1a71\/548f065806361d7e915cc89e?preset=543e41ca06361d414ze777c8\"><\/iframe>';
$newIframe = preg_replace('%<iframe(.*?)src=\\\\".*?dmcloud.*?\\\\/embed\\\\/.*\\\\/(.*?)\?.*?"><\\\\/iframe>%', '<iframe $1 src=\"My_New_String/$2\"<\\\\/iframe>', $iframe);
echo $newIframe;
```

---

**OUTPUT:**

```
<iframe  width=\"660\" height=\"370\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\"  src=\"My_New_String/548f065806361d7e915cc89e\"<\/iframe>
```

---

**DEMO:**

http://ideone.com/SrryIc

Comment: I forgot to specify i have string before <iframe and after /iframe>

Comment: Did you check http://ideone.com/SrryIc ? it works, your "real example" may be different from the on you've posted.

Comment: Yes i checked, i have the same first iframe as output

Comment: There's was an extra quote, it's working now. http://ideone.com/SrryIc , I've also updated the answer.

Comment: Yes thanks, and if i need to have the second id into a variable before preg_replace ?

Comment: You should make your question as clear  as much as possible before posting it. You din't mention anything in the original question and I don't have any example to work with.

Comment: "First I need to extract the second ID in src", i mentionned that. But thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use preg_replace

```
$html = '<iframe width=\"660\" height=\"370\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" src="sdfsdfsdfsdf"><\/iframe>';

$newhtml =   preg_replace('/src=[^<]*<\\\/iframe>/', 'src=\"'.$mySrc.'\"></iframe>', $html);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work..

```
$string = '<iframe width=\"660\" height=\"370\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" src=\"http:\/\/api.dmcloud.net\/embed\/53b5149794739966184c1a71\/548f065806361d7e915cc89e?preset=543e41ca06361d414ze777c8\"><\/iframe>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($string);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
$iframes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('iframe');
foreach ($iframes as $iframe) {
    echo preg_replace('~.*/(.*?)(?:\?.*|$)~', '$1', $iframe->getAttribute('src'));
}
```

Output:

> 548f065806361d7e915cc89e

Your regex doesn't work because `^src=\"(.)\"$`.

Says the string must start with `src="`. Then capture one character `.`. Then the string ends (`$`( with a `"`. If you added a quantifier to that `.` such as `*` (zero or more occurrences of the previous character) or `+` (one or more) and taken off the anchors it would have been closer. You still would have had to fiddle down to the ID though. For example `.*src=\"(.*?)\".*`, would have been closer because that captures everything in the `src` attribute (assuming there are only double quotes used at beginning and end).

The regex I've written goes to the last `/` and captures everything there until the first `?`, or the end of the string. It then replaces the string with just the captured value (which should be the id). A cleaner approach might be to use preg_match although you'd need to do an extra line to get it to output the captured value.

```
.*/(.*?)(?:\?.*|$)
```

Comment: And if there are multiple iframes ?

Comment: It's ok for extract the second ID, but how can i replace all src tag ?

Comment: @PedroLobito, yea? `foreach ($iframes as $iframe) {`

Comment: @ClémentAndraud you could do `str_replace($iframe->getAttribute('src'), 'whatever you want the src to be', $string);` (presumes src is unique or should be replace in all instances)..

Answer (score 1):

```
$test = '<iframe . . .';
$result = preg_match("/src.*\/([0-9a-f]*)\?/", $test, $out);
echo $out[1];
```